# data transfer between GPUs in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu

It is time-consuming to transfer data between different GPU devices,because it's likely that this process works like this:GPU1->CPU->GPU2.So is there any better way to transfer data between GPUs?In addition, assume that there are N threads,each of them have to read M elements from the global memory,What conditions should be met if I want to perform coalesced access?

Answer (score 4):

There is the [clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects.html) function, which is new as of OpenCL 1.2.

This function can be used to transfer memory buffers between devices in the same context.

Have never tried using this myself, so I don't know if it actually ends up being less expensive than doing a device->host->device copy (quite likely a number of implementations will do this anyway).

Comment: AFAIK all implementations have to go through host memory at the moment, but the difference is that they can do it as a sequence of DMA operations without extra involvement from the CPU and the user's code, which should give a bit of a speed up.

Comment: can't pci-e internal connections do it shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

Create the buffers using the concept of pinned buffers for the date in CPU then access among how many ever GPU's you would like to utilise...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the requirements in order to perform coalesced memory access, it is difficult to answer you without seeing your code.

But the idea is that you will gain in performance if threads are loading datas that are contiguous in memory. One generic idea to perform it is to use arrays instead of structs.